# How would you level this arm on a base?

Tags: technical-drawing

I was wondering how can I level smartly the following equipment's slighlty heavy arm.

The arm is fixed on a base with 4 big socket head screws. The same arm needs to be levelled via the 4 jacketscrews present. The base is fixed to the wall - see the image.

[image]
[image]

How would you level it on axis A and axis B? This is how I did it (struggling though): I unscrewed slightly the 4 big bolts (X,Y,Z,W) and then, with the level tool put to balance on axis A, I pulled the arm with great force in order to screw the jackscrew a or b. The same happened with the other axis.

How would you do it?

Comment: I would have used a surface level (a circular bubble level) and a second person to push it level to unload the bolts so I could turn them. Or anti-galling compound on the screws and a cheater pipe might allow you to turn them under load so no second person is needed.

Comment: Snuggly tighten the bolts W & Z and let screw b barely touching the base. tighten the bolts X & Y, using screw a to level the base about the axis B. Fine-tune the screws c & d to level the base with respect to axis A. This assumes the bolts W & Z are located furthest from the extended arm.

Comment: what is preventing the tips of the jackscrews from digging in